# Selenium eclipse Configuration with Webdriver 2 and Selenium Java Client Driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I was setting up the environment for selenium in eclipse for automation testing. I have downloaded the [Selenium Server 2.42.2](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar) as well as Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings for java from [here](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/selenium-java-2.42.2.zip)

My Question,

1. In Many website, eclipse has been configured with selenium webdriver alone. But in some other sites like [this](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/configure-eclipse-with-selenium-webdriver/) suggested to install only selenium client driver bindings alone

Initially, i have configured using selenium server alone and run the basic tests in firefox browser and its works fine. Please advice us the need to set up the selenium client driver binding libs for selenium.

1. is java client driver bindings is a sub set of selenium webdriver? can i run automated test scripts without java client driver jar?
2. what are the usage of selenium server and java client driver and how both differs from each other? any example would be much helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.Is java client driver bindings is a sub set of selenium webdriver? can i run automated test scripts without java client driver jar?**

If you want to write your selenium test cases using java, yes it is necessary to have.So you can say java client driver bindings is a subset of selenium webdriver to write and execute your test cases using java.

**2.What are the usage of selenium server and java client driver and how both differs from each other?**

Selenium Server.jar is used to run selenium server which was mandatory to run while there were Selenium RC only. Now with the arrival of Selenium 2.0 if your test cases are being executed on your local machine only you may not require Selenium Server.

If you want to run your test cases on a remote machine using RemoteWebdriver then only you would be needing Selenium Server.You can say its more or less the part of Selenium Grid.